# Ember JS - updating model property when fetching records after route has loaded

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Say I have the following code in my route:

```js
model() {
  return this.get('store').query('post', { author: 'John' });
},

actions: {
  fetchNewPosts: function() {
    this.get('store').query('post', { author: 'Sally' });
  }
}
```

Then the following in a component:

```js
modelSubset: function() {
  return this.get('model').slice(0, 10);
}.property('model', 'model.@each'),
```

The computed property in the component updates fine when the route is entered, and the posts by author "John" are fetched in the model hook.

However, if I later fire the action `fetchNewPosts` the records are being fetched and added to Ember data, but the computed property in the component does not update.

Is there a way to fetch new records such that the model property will update?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [kumkanillam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5771666/kumkanillam), I needed to be using query params to achieve this. Below is my new pattern which works:

Define "author" as a query param in the controller.

```js
queryParams: ['author',],
  author: "John",
```

In the model hook in the route, `params.author` fetches the value from the controller. In the `fetchJobs` action, I use `transitionTo` to  update the query param.

```js
model(params) {
    return this.get('store').query('posts', { author: params.author });
},

actions: {
  fetchJobs: function(authorName) {
    this.transitionTo({ queryParams: { author: authorName }});
  }
},
```

The code below causes the model to update when the query param changes.

```js
queryParams: {
  author: {
    refreshModel: true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not changing the `model` property so computed property will not run.
So you need to update `model` property,

```
fetchNewPosts: function() {
    this.get('store').query('post', { author: 'Sally' }).then(result=>{
      this.set('model',result);
     });
  }
```

Your computed property dependant key should include any of the property from model `model.@each.propertyName`.

Note: In your case I prefer to take a path using [dynamic segments](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_dynamic-segments) or [query params](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/routing/query-params/) approach.

Comment: I could not get the above to work, but I changed the model hook to `return this.get('store').findAll('post');` and then set the API to only send posts by John. Then this code: `this.get('store').query('post', { author: 'Sally' });` fetches additional posts, and updates the model without having to set it explicitly.

Somehow, using `findAll` in the model hook as opposed to a query, made the model property aware of the new records automatically.

Comment: Clearly `this.get('store').findAll('post'); and then set the API to only send posts by John` this is wrong approach. findAll should return all the data always thats how ember will assume..What exactly does not work?

Comment: Update question with your updated/tried code this will help

Comment: Your suggestion of using query params was the right way to do this.